# password to be used with external service

Tags: django, quickblox

I have an application that uses Django REST server on the backend and I'm integrating with a communication service called [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com) that provides real time text and video chat. I have to create a user as well as log in users with the service using a password, and I have some concerns.

The user will not need to know their password, it is something that is only going to be used in API calls from the server to an API endpoint provided by QuickBlox. The current plan is to make a random string of characters and store that value on the User object. The problem is that the quickblox password is stored in plain text, and I don't want that. Is there any way to store a hashed value of the generated password and then unhash it before sending it as the password in my request to Quickblox?

I was hoping to find something in [Django Password docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/), but there's nothing on unencrypting a hashed value, for good reason!

Maybe I'm going down the wrong path and someone has another suggestion. The problem is that I need to store a randomly generated password and use that password to issue requests to an external service.

Comment: If it were possible to reverse a hash, then we wouldn't use them. What you want is to *encrypt* the password using a *cipher*.

Comment: thank you, looking into that now

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read their official documentation about properly posting sensitive requests:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Signature_generation

As I see all requests are passed over HTTPS so there is no need for you to do anything else.

Also make sure you allow users to enter their own passwords or are having control of their Quickblox account as you are creating those accounts without their consent. What if some user of yours wanted to create an account in Quickblox and found that his email is already been taken?

Comment: thanks for the answer. The link you provided is for application authentication, which we issue request from the server and get back a token - that part we have done. Also, when creating an account on Quickblox, the account is per Application not global, and also we aren't passing their email, just a username (same as in Django) and a password. That password is what concerns me. It is HTTPS and is safe to issue requests, but I still would not like it to be stored in plain text.